# Eclipse RCP Project Explorer focus event

Tags: events, focus, project, rcp, explorer

Is there a way to detect when the user makes focus on the Project Explorer window in a RCP application? Is there an event I could use?

I researched and found that Project Explorer's id is org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer but I still didn't find any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener` to listen for changes to which part is active (and several other events).

You call the `IPartService` `addPartListener` method to set this up. You can get the part service in several ways depending on where you code is running. One of these is:

```java
IPartService partService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you! I used org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2 and it worked!